# Creating WAR using Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, war

I am creating war file from Netbeans. Previously I created jar file using Netbeans, it worked fine (in command prompt). But when I am running war file from command prompt, I am getting this error:

```
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from WebApplication2.war.
```

I have set main class from Netbeans during creation of jar

```
Project->properties->Run->Choosed main class)..
```

Do I have to set any mainclass during war creation (as web application does not have any main class, it just has JWS and servlets, how can we set main class)?

Comment: JARs can be run at the command prompt as they are just zip files. WAR (web archive) are meant for the web and have to entry point, so running at the prompt would cause an error. They can only be deployed to an application server such as Tomcat.

Comment: I have deployed war it is working fine but what if I want to run other than index page when i am running war??

Comment: What application server are you using, Tomcat, JBoss? You have two options: update the web.xml for, say, Tomcat, to include your file in the <welcome-file-list>, or you can do "servlet-mapping> in the web.xml file including in your war file.

Answer (score 3):

If your app is web project, Just say clean & build from Netbeans it will create a war file in your `project/target` directory

Comment: by doing this you should have `.war` file created

Comment: @JigarJoshi what if it's not a web project?

Comment: @Igor why do you want to create war for non web project ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi I want to migrate the project from NetBeans to Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you're asking... A main class is the first class invoked when a user runs your app. What is the first class invoked when a user visits your webapp?

It's going to be the classes bound to URLs inside your web.xml or bound with @Servlet annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Use web.xml to create an initial position for the war file to execute.
Insert your welcome file in here

```
 <root>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
 </root>
```

This will automatically select the file to run initially.